# CSS Float Right Number Value Disappears in Mobile Safari

Tags: css-float, mobile-safari

When I view the following on my iPhone, the contents of the second div don't appear.  I see both divs in chrome and safari on my computer.  Seems to be an issue with mobile Safari.  I found that if I replace the number, 123-456-7890, with text such as "Right Side Text", the issue goes away.

```
#bannerLeft {
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50%;
}
#bannerRight {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 30%;
}


<div id="bannerLeft">Left Side Text</div> 
<div id="bannerRight">123-456-7890</div>
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you never style through `id` selectors, is a really bad practice, but this is easy to fix:

```
.banner {
 font-size: 1.7em;
 font-weight: bold;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner.left {
 float: left;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 50%;
}

.banner.right {
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 text-align: right;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
 *zoom: 1;
}

<div class="clearfix">
 <div class="banner left">Left Side Text</div> 
 <div class="banner right">123-456-7890</div>
</div>
```

The problem may be due to some paddings or margins each browser has as default, the simplest solution in here was to add the `box-sizing` css3 property, which stops this problem to happen.

Also when floating things you may want to wrap those elements into a `clearfix` element to prevent overlapping.

Try the codepen I put together, maybe it can help.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LELrYd

I also float everything to the left, you'll get quite the same result, just notice the text align property, if this is not your case you can float to right and it would still works.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the information, and for providing a cleaner solution.  Unfortunately, my issue still exists.  Using the html and css you provided, I still don't see the number in the right div in mobile safari, unless I prepend or append a character to the number.  Seems like an odd mobile safari bug, not sure.  Text shows up, numbers with dashes do no show up.

Comment: it is really weird, I tested on my iphone and it works, which version do you have?